# animation problem when value changes while setTimeout timer's running

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
function wallpaperMediaPropertiesListener(event) {

    // reset animation
    test.stop(true);
    test.css('margin-left', 0);
    
    // set song title.
    test.text(event.title);
    var testWidth = test.outerWidth();
    
    // clone text
    $('.test-copy').remove();
    if (testWidth > $('#line1').width()) {
        test.clone().css({'margin-left': gap, 'font-size': '1.05vh'}).removeClass().addClass('test-copy').insertAfter(test);
    }
    
    // move text
    let speed = 5;
    function shiftingAnimation() {
        let timer = setTimeout(() => {
            test.animate({'margin-left': -(testWidth + gap)}, {
            duration: Math.abs((testWidth + gap) * 100 / speed),
            easing: 'linear',
            complete: function () {
                test.css({'margin-left': 0});
                clearTimeout(timer);
                shiftingAnimation();
            }
            });
        }, 3000);
    }

    // first execution
    if (testWidth > $('#line1').width()) {
        setTimeout(shiftingAnimation, 3000);
    }

}
```

event.title returns song name that is playing. wallpaperMediaPropertiesListener function will be triggered when song changes.

animation starts after 3s delay when testWidth > #line1 width. when animation ends, it repeats itself with 3s delay each time. if event.title value changes, it resets animation and start from first 3s delay and so on.

but the problem is when event.title value changes during 3s delay, animation is applied whether the condition (testWidth > #line1) is true or false. and looks like its using previous testWidth to animate.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the event.title as parameter not event:

1 - In your caller function pass the event.title

`wallpaperMediaPropertiesListener(event.title)`

And then:

```
`function wallpaperMediaPropertiesListener(title) {

// reset animation
test.stop(true);
test.css('margin-left', 0);

// set song title.
test.text(title);
var testWidth = test.outerWidth();

// clone text
$('.test-copy').remove();
if (testWidth > $('#line1').width()) {
    test.clone().css({'margin-left': gap, 'font-size': '1.05vh'}).removeClass().addClass('test-copy').insertAfter(test);
}

// move text
let speed = 5;
function shiftingAnimation() {
    let timer = setTimeout(() => {
        test.animate({'margin-left': -(testWidth + gap)}, {
        duration: Math.abs((testWidth + gap) * 100 / speed),
        easing: 'linear',
        complete: function () {
            test.css({'margin-left': 0});
            clearTimeout(timer);
            shiftingAnimation();
        }
        });
    }, 3000);
}

// first execution
if (testWidth > $('#line1').width()) {
    setTimeout(shiftingAnimation, 3000);
}
```

}`